# XML to SAS Dataset - Performance

Tags: xml, sas

I have a requirement to convert a ODM xml file to sas dataset. i have used below method to do that, but the execution time is more as it is  a 25MB file. Is there any way to do it faster.

filename NHL  "/path/ODM.xml";

filename map "/path/odm_map.map";

libname NHL xmlv2 xmlmap=map;

proc copy in=nhl out=work;

run;

ODM.xml is a 25 mb file so when i try to copy those datasets present in NHL to work library, it's taking allmost 10 min, is there any way to reduce the execution time.

Comment: How often do you have to copy ODM files to SAS ?

Comment: It's only once I have to copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this as a test and compare times. Download any tool that does this (here is one: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=xmltocsv), convert to CSV then do a proc import into SAS.

When I work with XML and SAS, I prefer outside tools for XML. They have a more automated way of handling the XML mapping vs the SAS XML maps. It may cause CSV file explosion so it is a test. However, XML does not map easily into rows/columns so YMMV.